# PHP: How to save mysql to excel file to a directory and not prompt user to download

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have got a script that will take my sql statement and convert to excel. I would like the excel file to be saved in a folder instead of prompting to download cause I would like to work on the excel file.

MY SCRIPT

```
<?php


/* Connecting, selecting database */
$db_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db_link) {
   die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Could not select database");

/* Performing SQL query */
$sQuery="select * from comments where `comment` like '%apple%';";


$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or die();
$count = mysql_num_fields($rResult);

$html = '<table border="1"><thead><tr>%s</tr><thead><tbody>%s</tbody></table>';
$thead = '';
$tbody = '';
$line = '<tr>%s</tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){      
  $thead .= sprintf('<th>%s</th>',mysql_field_name($rResult, $i));
}


while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rResult))){
  $trow = '';

  foreach($row as $value){
   $trow .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value);
  }

  $tbody .= sprintf($line, $trow);

}


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

print sprintf($html, $thead, $tbody);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You're not actually creating an Excel file, just a file that Excel can read.... there really is a pretty big difference between html markup and either BIFF or OfficeOpenXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the file download headers and save the file

```
/*
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print sprintf($html, $thead, $tbody);
exit;
*/

file_put_contents("exportfile.xls", $html.$thead.$tbody); // make sure that write permissions are set
```

Comment: Formatting has to be your own, you can add new lines to those. But that's the way to save your file